# Can't update Image binding from BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, backgroundworker, mvvm-light

I am getting:

> "An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Must create DependencySource on same Thread as
>   the DependencyObject."

XAML:

```
  <ListBox x:Name="AutoListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding AutoList}" Visibility="{Binding AutoListVisibility}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                   <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler"></EventSetter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImgSource}"></Image>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
    private Visibility isBusyVisibility;

    public Visibility IsBusyVisibility
    {
        get { return isBusyVisibility; }
        set
        {
            isBusyVisibility = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsBusyVisibility");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<GenericPictureName> autoList;

    public ObservableCollection<GenericPictureName> AutoList
    {
        get { return autoList; }
        set
        {
            autoList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("AutoList");
        }
    }
public AutoAlbumTrackAssociationViewModel()
    {
        _bwArtist = new BackgroundWorker();
        _bwArtist.DoWork += bwArtist_DoWork;
    }

private void bwArtist_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        AutoList = new ObservableCollection<GenericPictureName>(LastFMLookup.ArtistQuery(e.Argument.ToString()));

        RaisePropertyChanged("AutoList");
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsBusyVisibility");
    }
```

Model:

```
public class GenericPictureName
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    private ImageSource imgSource;

    public ImageSource ImgSource
    {
        get { return imgSource; }
        set
        {
            imgSource = value;
        }
    }


    public GenericPictureName()
    {

    }

    public GenericPictureName(string name, string image)
    {
        Name = name;
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(image); ;
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
        ImgSource = bitmapImage;
    }

}
```

If I remove the binding of the image from the XAML file, I get back a list in the UI that displays the names fine. I also did a test method that didn't use a backgroundworker to verify that it worked correctly. I also tried invoking the main thread and still got the same error. I am unsure of what to try next.

Comment: In `GenericPictureName` method, call `bitmapImage.Freeze()` before setting it to the ImgSource property `ImgSource = bitmapImage;`. See if it works.

Comment: Did not work. The BitmapImage's weren't able to be frozen.

Comment: The text "Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject". Did you do any kind of search on the web or on StackOverflow for that text? What did you find? Why did the information you found not help you understand the problem you're having? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for good advice on how to present your question in a clear, useful way. Especially note the first item: "Search, and research".

Comment: I did that is why I am asking... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image parameter refers to a local file, it should be sufficient to specify that the BitmapImage is loaded immediately by setting `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`, and then freeze it.

```
public GenericPictureName(string name, string image)
{
    Name = name;
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(image);
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
    bitmapImage.Freeze();
    ImgSource = bitmapImage;
}
```

In case it's a remote resource you may first download the image buffer and put it into a MemoryStream, from which you finally load the image:

```
public GenericPictureName(string name, string image)
{
    Name = name;
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    var imageBuffer = new WebClient().DownloadData(image);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBuffer))
    {
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.StreamSource = ms;
        bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
    }
    bitmapImage.Freeze();
    ImgSource = bitmapImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try setting EnableCollectionSynchronization on your collection

```
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(AutoList, _itemsLock);
```

and then clear() and Add() to it in your worker method instead of recreating it